# dumb-init No such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to use dumb-init to run a script that tests a jetty servlet in my docker container, but whenever I try to call dumb-init it fails with the message:

```
local-test | [dumb-init] /var/lib/jetty/testrun.bash: No such file or directory
```

But if I use bash instead of dumb-init it happily runs.  The file exists and has the correct permissions.  I even stripped out the execution and just left the bang and an echo statement and it fails the same way.  The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/dumb-init /bin/bash
echo "Tests Running!"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you please add `ls -la /bin/dumb-init` output? also with which user are you trying to run the script?

Comment: Could you provide full Docker file ?
Did you try to add "pip install dumb-init" to your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Just to echo this again: this will not be solvable without seeing at least the Dockerfile